# TFS (CI) - Only one branch has just been check-in/pushed to be built

Tags: tfs, build, msbuild, azure-devops, tfsbuild

I'm trying to deploy a Continuous Integration server where I work.
We used TFVC with the branch to release strategy, but we are having difficulty with something that should be trivial.
We only need the build on the branch that was checked in.
Is it possible to do this without having to change the build definition every time a new branch is created?
I do not want to map the entire folder structure of the repository. Imagine having 10 branches and every check-in, build all? Does not make sense!
Anyone have any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CI build for TFVC can’t map and just build target branch like build for Git.
There are some workarounds:

1. Clone a build definition and change source mapping, Path filters of triggers for each branch.
2. Add a PowerShell step/task to get recent check-in change by calling [get changesets](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/tfvc/changesets#in-a-date-range) Rest API, then store the related solution/project files in a variable by using [Logging Commands](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md), then build these solutions/projects

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this is frustrating!
I will evaluate your suggestions to try to implement them.

Comment: @starian chen, could you please elaborate your 2. solution? We have a folder in our TFVC containing various branches. I would like to setup an CI Build for this folder, which only builds the branch that received a changeset. The problem is, that when specifying the build, the first step  is to map a repository path to a local path ("Get Sources").This is kind of unfortunate, because i have to map the whole folder, even if i only need to build one branch, which increases the duration of the CI Build. Is it possible to inject a variable in the "Get Sources" step to only map the current branch?

Comment: @SvenLauterbach No, it is impossible.